# BiometricPromptCompat: Disable Iris/Face recognition (only allow fingerprints)

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I've got an app that uses BiometricPrompt to implement biometric based authentication. I've noted that some devices offer Iris/Face recognition as an option alongside fingerprint scan.

I want my app to only allow fingerprint scanning. It it possible to only allow this? Alternatively, would it be possible to determine what method the user selected to authenticate so I could deny the request in my callback code?

Comment: There's currently no way that I'm aware of to do this when using `BiometricPrompt`. You can use the old `FingerprintManager` class for the time being (yes, it's deprecated, but I still haven't heard of any plans to remove it). One downside of using `FingerprintManager` is that you may have less control over the appearance of the prompt on devices with in-screen fingerprint sensors.

Comment: hello did you find any solution ?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution? I also want to remove face id and allow only touch id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My worry is invalid.

Here's the offical word:

> While both strong and weak biometrics will be allowed to unlock a
> device, weak biometrics:
>
> - Require the user to re-enter their primary PIN, pattern, password or a
>   strong biometric to unlock a device after a 4-hour window of
>   inactivity, such as when left at a desk or charger. This is in
>   addition to the 72-hour timeout that is enforced for both strong and
>   weak biometrics.
> - ***Are not supported by the forthcoming BiometricPrompt
>   API, a common API for app developers to securely authenticate users on
>   a device in a modality-agnostic way***.
> - Can't authenticate payments or
>   participate in other transactions that involve a KeyStore auth-bound
>   key.
> - Must show users a warning that articulates the risks of using the
>   biometric before it can be enabled.
>
> **These measures are intended to
> allow weaker biometrics, while reducing the risk of unauthorized
> access.**

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/better-biometrics-in-android-p.html

Answer (score 4):

As per latest Android Biometric API docs, there is no way to allow only fingerprint scanning.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found solution for this issue
-->setAllowedAuthenticators(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG) did the trick

```
BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Confirm to authenticate")
            .setDescription("Touch the fingerprint sensor")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
            .setAllowedAuthenticators(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
            .build();

    biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the CryptoObject in `authenticate` method to enable strong authentication.
In Android, there are  different measures for face/Iris and Fingerprint.

https://source.android.com/security/biometric/measure

Comment: I've already passed in the crypto object (AES/CBC/PCKS7) into the authenticate method. I'm not sure how that would help with disabling  Iris/Face scanning altogether? I'm aware API 30 allows you request BIOMETRIC_STRONG via setAllowedAuthenticators(int) but I want to only allow fingerprint authentication regardless of what the OEM reports as 'strong' (for compliance reasons in the industry the app operates in)

Comment: CDD requires that all 'strong' biometrics meet the exact same compliance guidelines. That is true across all OEMs and all devices.